# phpUnit Testing curl operations

Tags: php, curl, phpunit

I have class and I'm using it to curl operations (sending post data, getting source of website etc).

Now I want to make unit tests to it, but I dont have idea **how I can test it** ?

Example usage of my class:

```
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setUrl('http://example.php');
$curl->setReturn(true);
$source = $curl->execute();
```

Have you any advices for me ?

Comment: I already wrote some test classes but I dont know how to do it to test curl or ftp.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an abstraction to curl, namely [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2). During unit tests, you don't use the curl adapter but the mock adapter.

The library is stable and unit-tested, so you don't have to test your curl usage anymore, but can safely work with the mock data.